# Look up value in array and return all other values in row where the value is found

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to find a certain value in an array and return all other values in the row where that value is found. I tried several combined `INDEX, MATCH, VLOOKUP` array formulas but I'm no closer to finding a solution.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

I'd like a formula to find the value in `G2` in the array `A2:E5` and then return all other values in each row where it's found to columns `H,I,J,K`

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be really appreciated ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

Formula in `H2`:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A2:$E2,$G$2)>0,INDEX($A2:$E2,,SMALL(($A2:$E2<>$G$2)*COLUMN($A2:$E2),COUNTIF($A2:$E2,$G$2)+COLUMN(A1))),"")
```

Entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag down and right...

[image]

[image]

Comment: @StijnMinneboo, glad it works. Please consider marking the question as answered.

Comment: Just did. Thanks again :-)